# CGAL - building INSTALL .sln ,error MSB3073: The command "setlocal"

Tags: visual-studio, qt, cmake, cgal

I have a problem while compiling CGAL I followed the steps here : http://www.cse.msu.edu/~ytong/CGAL_installation.ppt I'm using VS2013 , cgal 4.9.1 , BOOST 1.59.0 ,Qt5.7.1

but when I reach at building INSTALL .sln step it show the following error:

```
Error   1   error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  132 5   INSTALL
```

output message :

```
   1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  -- Install configuration: "Debug"
1>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL/share/doc/CGAL-4.9.1/AUTHORS
1>  -- Up-to-date: C:/Program Files (x86)/CGAL/share/doc/CGAL-4.9.1/CHANGES
1>  CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:39 (file):
1>    file INSTALL cannot set permissions on "C:/Program Files
1>    (x86)/CGAL/share/doc/CGAL-4.9.1/CHANGES"
1>  
1>  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

any help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> file INSTALL cannot set permissions on "C:/Program Files

Building the INSTALL target must create files in the Program Files directory, and this requires elevated privileges.

The solution is to run Visual Studio as Administrator when you do the INSTALL build.

Comment: You shouldn't overwrite your question with an entirely new set of errors because now my answer no longer makes sense. In your case where my answer got you further along, you would vote my answer up for helping you, and then append to your question appropriately with what happens after you build as Administrator.